# Stack Exchange Android app LaTeX not displayed correctly

Tags: discussion, android-app, mathjax

Why doesn't the Stack Exchange Android app display LaTeX as mathematical formulas correctly instead of just showing the LaTeX code?
It just shows the raw LaTeX code which doesn't help when trying to read the mathematical formulas.